# Invalid Target in Intruder

Tags: burp-suite

starting with Burp Suite and trying to breach DVWA, I am bugged with this error: "Invalid Target".

[image: BURP SUITE INTRUDER ERROR]

Damn Vulnerable Web App is actually hosted on the private net as Burp shows:

[image: DVWA]

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Change your IP so it doesn't end in 0

Comment: @schroeder this actually worked! Is this a known issue?